# Get value of a property and store as array in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I want to get all values of a property and store it as an array. I have tried this way

```
data() {
    return {
       roomList: null
    }
},
methods: {
     getRooms() {
        var that = this
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/roomList')
              .then(function(response) {
                that.roomList = response.data
            })
        let roomLists = that.roomList.map(i => i.name) //getting the property values
        return roomLists;
    },

},
mounted: function () {
        this.getRooms()
},
```

I'm quite sure that I put the `map` function in the wrong place. I have tried putting it in the `data` but it doesn't work as well. I can't seem to figure out where I should put that function.
If anyone can help me, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: `that.roomList = response.data` executes after `let roomLists = that.roomList.map` ... because asynchrony ... and since there's asynchrony, `return roomLists` is meaningless too - but then again, that return value is never used, so, no harm there - in fact, no need for `let roomLists = that.roomList.map(i => i.name)` at all in that function ... where do you need this "list of names"

Comment: `return roomLists` - this doesn't make sense because it's this problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, take a look at following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
       roomList: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    roomLists() {
      return this.roomList?.map(i => i.name)
    }
  },
  methods: {
     getRooms() {
       axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then((response) => {
          this.roomList = response.data
      })
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getRooms()
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.26.1/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPh3uwgU5qEMipS/VOmRqynnMXGGSRv+72H/N260MQeXZIK4PG48401Bsby9Nq5P5fz7hy5UGNmC/W1Z51h2GQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="demo">
  {{roomLists}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What I'd do here is save the full `roomsList` data in your `data` property and create a computed property to extract just the names that stays in-sync with the backing data.

You should also initialise `roomsList` as an array

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({ roomsList: [] }),
  computed: {
    roomNames: ({ roomsList }) => roomsList.map(({ name }) => name)
  },
  methods: {
    async getRooms () {
      const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/roomList');
      this.roomsList = data;
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getRooms()
  },
};
```

Your template could then look something like this

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="roomName in roomNames">{{ roomName }}</li>
</ul>
```